# Can we add some sort of "gift"-like feature for excellent users?

Tags: feature-request

Just suggesting a sort of thing where I could award someone a trophy, maybe.

For example, if someone writes a really good question, I could award them a "Great First Question!" trophy.

Some trophies could possibly have reputation associated with them.

Comment: It exists, and is called a bounty. Alternatively, there are badges to reward positive participation (mostly).

Comment: @ArtOfCode I mean personally to another user (and not **always** reputation).

Comment: That kind of misses the whole point of the site - it is about the content, not the person posting it.

Comment: Would it be wrong for me to include a donation button in my profile?

Answer (score 5):

> For example, if someone writes a really good question, I could award them a "Great First Question!" trophy.

Upvote! That's why we have the upvote button. This also applies to all posts.

> Some trophies could possibly have reputation associated with them.

They are called bounties but can only be awarded to answers...

---

The point here is that Stack Exchange is ***focused on its content***, not its users. We ***aren't a social media*** site or some reward site where good posts means tons of free rewards like actual items (well, there is swag...). Anyways, how would you be able to give the person the reward? It's not like someone is going to give you their address let alone to anyone online? No one's opinion is good enough to be able to see if a question is of excellent quality by themselves (mostly). We do have badges that do reward users though for their excellent work! You can read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow/256084#256084) for more information.

Comment: Emphasis on "focused on its content, not its users". Many sites nowadays are what are called "Social Media" sites. Stack Exchange sites might be described as "*Anti*social Media" sites.

Comment: I am fairly new here and noticed the OP got down voted `-10`. Now is the _massive_ down vote as a result of (1). __it's a duplicate qiestion and OP didn't do enough to find it__, (2). __Poorly structured OP or detail lacking OP__, or (3). __Said something terrible in comments__.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I agree that it seems extreme, but this is the culture on Stack Exchange.